# Hide related list on Content Document page in experience cloud

Tags: contentversion, contentdocument, experience-cloud

Is there a way to hide these related lists? I finally got this url (https://HOST.cs66.force.com/PORTAL_NAME/s/contentdocument/contentDocId)  which shows the content document and we can preview document and download it here which is great but we don't want to show our users the Shared with, versions and other related lists. I have tried to remove these from Content Version Page layout but it still shows up here.

The second workaround I have tried is to open this url in an iframe, host the iframe in an aura component which is an aura app and change the css of related list. But since the origin of aura app is different than community origin ( Aura app -> lightning.force.com and community origin -> cs66.force.com/PORTAL_NAME), I can't even change the css of the related list.[image]

Comment: Please share the URL, if possible to get the right context of the issue. You have the options to hide related list on objects. Please try that as the first option.

Comment: Yeah that's the first thing I did, tried to remove related lists from the layout but it was still coming up on communities. I tried the css fix and that resolved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These related lists are indeed not found as "common" related list on Content Version page layout to easily remove them via setup configuration.

**Workaround**: under Theme section of Experience builder, add custom css to hide the right section column containing the Shared with, Versions and other related lists:

```
.forceCommunityFileDetailPage .slds-size_1-of-3 {
    display: none;
}
```

For more details where to access the CSS editor check this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_customize_css.htm)

> Note: Use custom CSS sparingly. Future releases of template components might not support your CSS customizations

This custom CSS workaround is inspired by Chris Gardner's best answer posted for a similar question on Trailhead community [Hide File Details from Customer Users in Community (Experience) Cloud](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A905TSAR)

Comment: Nice. I applied the css and it works fine. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: @AJM Good to know this worked out for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also customise the File detail experience cloud page and leave only record detail component on the page or a custom component if you'd like.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).